# Русский язык .вуз. транскрипция

Tags: фонетика, транскрипция

Помогите пожалуйста. ПРАВИЛЬНО ЛИ ВЫПОЛНЕНА ТРАНСКРИПЦИЯ?:
Офицеры-[а/ф’и/цэ́/ры].
Необразованный [н’и/аб/ра/зо́/ва/н ̅ый’]
Требования [тр’э́/бъ/въ /н’и/jъ].

Спокойствие [спа/ко́jст/в’и/jэ].
Человек [ч’ь/ла/в’э́к].
Несколько- [н’э́с/къл’/къ].

Comment: Отметьте ответ галочкой, если он вам помог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Офицеры-[Λ- ф’и-цэ́-ры].

Необразованный-[н’ь - ъ - брΛ –зо́ – въ -н‾ый]  неверное деление на слоги по закону восходящей звучности, послеударные -ъ, первый предударный и абсолютное начало - крышечка.

Требования [тр’э́ - бъ - въ - н’и - jь].

Спокойствие [сп Λ -ко́й- ств’и-jь]. Человек [ч’ь - лΛ -  в’э́к].

Несколько- [н’э́ - скъл’- къ].

По-моему, так.

Comment: А лабиализацию тоже нужно было? Тогда точки поставьте вверху между ударным гласным и мягким согласным.